How to use react-admin with require?
I'm trying to make a CRUD system for XWiki objects and I'd like to use react-admin for it. Here's how XWiki docs say we can integrate libraries into XWiki: How to integrate React and XWiki?. Or here's an article for integrating javascript libraries in general: Integrating JavaScript Libraries.
Following the react tutorial, it says to do:
require.config({
  paths: {
    'react': 'https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min',
    'react-dom': 'https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min'
  }
})

define('likeButton', ['react'], function(React) {
  'use strict';
...

That works and I get like button rendered:

But once I add:
require.config({
  paths: {
    'react': 'https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min',
    'react-dom': 'https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min',
    'react-admin': 'https://unpkg.com/react-admin@4.16.16/dist/index.js'
  }
})

define('likeButton', ['react',  'react-admin'], function(React, ReactAdmin) {
  'use strict';

The like button isn't rendered anymore and I get error in the console:
require.min.js?r=1:5 Uncaught Error: Script error for "react-admin", needed by: likeButton
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.min.js?r=1:5:1795)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.min.js?r=1:5:17084)

